# What does [1] mean in an XSLT sort?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm spelunking some XSLT code (applying to XML data) in order to comprehend it and re-write it in Python (applying to an equivalent SQL data store).  As you can imagine, I'm trying to get through it with as little understanding of XSLT as I can get away with, although still spending plenty of time looking up syntax.  Here's one I can't figure out myself, TIA.

The XSL script is largely the following:

```
<xsl:template match="dataroot" mode="prior_install">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Data" group-by="SN">
        <xsl:variable name="sn_list" as="node()*">
            <xsl:perform-sort select="current-group()">
                <xsl:sort select="INIT_DT" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:sort select="COPY" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:sort select="RCODE[1]" data-type="text" order="descending"/>
            </xsl:perform-sort>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="$sn_list">
            (IRRELEVANT MATERIAL REMOVED)
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

What does the `[1]` mean in the `RCODE[1]` sort key?  How would this differ from sorting by just plain `RCODE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression:

```
select="RCODE[1]"
```

means select the first `RCODE` child.

If a `Data` element has more than one `RCODE` children, and you try to sort by all of them at once, you will get an error (in XSLT 2.0) because a sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the `@select` attribute of `xsl:sort` - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#err-XTTE1020

Comment: Ah, I saw a reference with that kind of description, but I didn't understand it because it didn't talk about having multiple children, and because my XML data is standing in for a database table, I never have multiple `RCODE` values on one branch.  Nicely explained.